# iOS -- UITextView still putting period before double space if autocorrectionType is UITextAutoCorrectionTypeNo

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, error-correction

I want to turn off this behavior.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a feature in the iOS Settings. Only the user can turn that off.

Settings > General > Keyboard > "." Shortcut

However, you could always monitor the `valueChanged` event of the UITextField and remove any characters that you don't want.